# Is it possible to restore a backup of a physical machine to a machine with disparate hardware?

Tags: windows, backup, sysprep

I have seen some backup software advertise the ability to restore an image of a physical machine to completely different hardware. Is this really possible? Also, is this easily done with sysprep?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since this is Serverfault I'll assume you are referring to a server.

And...since you are mentioning sysprep, I'm guessing you are looking for a Windows answer.

Yes, it is possible, it depends on the backup software used, and other info you are leaving out.

Backup Exec has their "Restore Anywhere Technology" for example, but others will do it too.

Acronis has their "Universal Restore" option for example.

Comment: Symantec Backup Exec was going to be my answer. We tested it at work and it went flawlessly. Was hilarious to see a decommissioned server running on an HP laptop.